# Odd object behaviour

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing a small website for a newspaper and I'm trying to make the home page to show the latest news and a photo for each. I use Firebase Realtime Database and Firestorage to store the news and the photos. When getting the data and showing it I save all the data first in an object array and then displaying it (so it remains in order).

The problem is that when I'm calling the function to display it the links to the photos don't appear.

I tried outputting the array with `console.log(arrayName)` and everything looks like it should. But when I try `console.log(arrayName[1].sos)` it shows nothing.

```
db.collection("articole").orderBy("data", "asc").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        articolTmp = {
          titlu: doc.data().titlu,
          subtitlu: doc.data().subtitlu,
          id: doc.id,
          poza: doc.data().poza,
          data: doc.data().data,
          sos: ""
        };
        articole.push(articolTmp);
    });
    show();
});

function show(){
  for(let i = 1; i < articole.length; ++i){
    var pathReference = storage.ref('pozeArticole/' + articole[i].poza);
    pathReference.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
       articole[i].sos = url;
    });
}
  showw();
}

function showw(){
  // this is the console.log I was talking about
  console.log(articole);
  for(let i = 1; i < articole.length; ++i){
    console.log(articole[i].sos);
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var titlu = document.createElement("h3");
    var subtitlu = document.createElement("p");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var poza = document.createElement("img");
    poza.src = articole[i].sos;
    poza.alt = "alt";
    link.href = "viz.html?id=" + articole[i].id;
    titlu.innerHTML = articole[i].titlu;
    subtitlu.innerHTML = articole[i].subtitlu;
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
    link.appendChild(titlu);
    div.appendChild(link);
    div.appendChild(subtitlu);
    div.appendChild(poza);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `show` function. The last line of code which calls `showw` is executed before the line "above it" which is `articole[i].sos = url;`. Why is that? Because you are using an asynchronous operation. The code that gets the download url is executed in a different thread. Whenever that code finished, the block you provided (`articole[i].sos = url;`) will get executed. I recommend reading about asynchronous operations and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

So, to solve your problem, you have ti move the `showw` call inside the block above it. The block should be:

```
pathReference.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
   articole[i].sos = url;
   showw();
});`
```

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me! Your solution doesn't work how I want, but at least you put me back on track. I actually had something similar to what you suggested and the problem is that because the asynchronous behaviour the news get displayed in the wrong order.

Comment: No problem!
To keep the order. I suggest you move `showw` to its original place (under or above the block), then move the code that displays the image inside the block. By "the code that displays the image" I mean `var poza = document.createElement("img");
    poza.src = articole[i].sos;
    poza.alt = "alt";`

Comment: Did it and now it works. But I gave each div an id (used the news id) so I could append each photo to it's div. Because of that `showw` must be called before `getDownloadURL()`. [These are showw and show functions now!](https://pastebin.com/GyTu4cVW)